# WinForm : Bind Dictionary string keys to ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

How to bind Dictionary keys (string) to listBox in Winform?

Im trying :

```
groupDict = new Dictionary<string, UploadThread>();
listBoxRunning.DataSource = groupDict.Keys.ToList<string>();
```

and when i add new items to Dictionary, no changes in listBox.

Comment: When you call ToList a new List of strings is created from the Keys property. It is not the same list, so adding elements to the dictionary doesn't affect the list binded to the listbox

Comment: i  decided to bind with a new key List every time i change the Dictionary. it works, but i feel that this is not the best way how to do

Comment: You can use a `BindingList<string>`, use it as datasource for your ListBox and when you add/remove elements from the dictionary do the same on the BindingList

Comment: Been a while, but wouldn't it work if you bound the listBox.DataSource to the groupDict.Keys collection? This avoid calling ToList() every time, and avoids creating a new List<string> everytime.